# qt quick 2 printing with console

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I can't figure out how to print with console.log inside a qt quick application.

I have this .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick
CONFIG += c++11
CONFIG += console

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)
```

this is main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

this is main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
   visible: true
   Text {
      anchors.centerIn: parent
      text: "Hello World"
   }
   Component.onCompleted: console.log("foo")
}
```

Why it doens't print "foo"?

Comment: That should work; your use of `console.log` looks fine.

Comment: I mean your `main.qml` looks fine.  If you run, `qmlscene main.qml` you should see your message on the console.

Comment: Which platform and Qt version?

Comment: @nfranklin it doens't print anything even with qmlscene

Comment: @Mitch linux 64 bit (Fedora) qt 5.5

Comment: If you add a red `Rectangle` to the scene, do you see it when you run the application?

Comment: @Mitch yes i've also tried to change it's color inside onCompleted and it works. For what i can see it works everything except console :| (and the debugger of qt creator but this is another story :p)

Comment: That's really weird. What happens if you remove the `CONFIG += console`? That's only relevant for Windows, anyway. If that doesn't work, perhaps you can upload your entire project for us to try out. :)

Comment: @Mitch it doesn't change anything. This is the entire project (i've just created a default project with qtcreator and added the onCompleted line) and also it should work (if I am not wrong) even by simply launching main.qml with qmlscene but it doesn't even in that case.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just trying crazy things because I don't know what else it could be. :p Sounds like an issue with your environment/setup.

Comment: You can always try qmake and then rebuild project :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solved it was caused by the fact that Fedora has *.debug=false inside /etc/xdg/QtProject/qtlogging.ini and that prevents the messages to be printed. To "solve" this it's enough to create the file ~/.config/QtProject/qtlogging.ini with this content:

```
[Rules]
default=true
```